# Swift 4 Firebase Storage Image Download within a "For Loop"

Tags: swift, firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a firebase snapshot with multiple returned nodes:

[Screenshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WVva.png)

And try to use a "for loop" to go through it. Within each loop, I would like to download a image file from Firebase Storage:

```
let projectReviews = projectDB.queryOrdered(byChild: "contractorID").queryEqual(toValue: contractorID)

    projectReviews.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            guard let value = child.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { continue }
                if value["projectStatus"] as? String ?? "" == "Completed" && value["recommend"] != nil {

                counter += 1
                    print("this is how many times this for loop has go through \(counter) at \(child.key)")

                    //Fetch and display the data.

                    var downloadURL :String
                    downloadURL = "Projects/" + "\(child.key)" + "--00"
                    print("---" + downloadURL)
                    print("downloadURL before download---" + downloadURL )
                    var imgURL = self.storageRef.child("")
                    imgURL = self.storageRef.child(downloadURL)
                    print("downloadURL after assign download URL ---" + downloadURL )
                    imgURL.getData(maxSize: Int64(1 * 1024 * 2000), completion: { (data, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                            print("===This is image Download error on=== \n")
                            print(counter)
                            print("\(downloadURL)")
                            return
                        } else {
                        //Do something

                        }
                    })

}
```

As you see here, I have put a few print command to tell me what is going on with the downloadURL variable.

The Problem:

on the 2nd loop, the downloadURL variable, when actually try to download the file, is still using the previous loop's value, even though before "getData" the value is correct:

```
this is how many times this for loop has go through 1 at vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001
---Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00
downloadURL before download---Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00
downloadURL after assign download URL ---Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00
this is how many times this for loop has go through 2 at vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0002
---Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0002--00
downloadURL before download---Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0002--00
downloadURL after assign download URL ---Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0002--00
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00 does not exist."     UserInfo={object=Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00, bucket=bafo-1c3c8.appspot.com, ResponseBody=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: bafo-1c3c8.appspot.com/Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00</Details></Error>, data=<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2731 2e302720 656e636f 64696e67 3d275554 462d3827 3f3e3c45 72726f72 3e3c436f 64653e4e 6f537563 684b6579 3c2f436f 64653e3c 4d657373 6167653e 54686520 73706563 69666965 64206b65 7920646f 6573206e 6f742065 78697374 2e3c2f4d 65737361 67653e3c 44657461 696c733e 4e6f2073 75636820 6f626a65 63743a20 6261666f 2d316333 63382e61 70707370 6f742e63 6f6d2f50 726f6a65 6374732f 76353756 5467595a 4c685170 7a57486a 4c306131 6b733150 494a6d31 52695339 61574631 4f6a5854 63635963 524b6453 67525a6f 54473832 2d2d2d2d 30303031 2d2d3030 3c2f4465 7461696c 733e3c2f 4572726f 723e>, NSLocalizedDescription=Object Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00 does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
Projects/vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001--00
```

as you see from the log, if I print the downloadURL variable within getData closure, it contain the previous value "vzzzzzzzzzzzzzz----0001"

Is the way I am doing supported? If not, how could I work around it, so the image can be displayed within the same loop?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. This should able to apply to all cases in this asynchronous calls with Firebase Database.

It is a two part solution.

First, define a function with call back to query and store the data, as a class, in an array:

```
  func getList(callback: @escaping ((_ data:[reviewContent]) -> Void)) {
    var contentArray :[content] = [content]()
    let someDB = dbRef!.child("someDB")

    let returns = someDB.queryOrdered(byChild: "contractorID").queryEqual(toValue: someValue)

    returns.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            guard let value = child.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { continue }

            let contentEntry = content()
            contentEntry.ID = child.key
            //store any additional values where defined in the class

            contentArray.append(contentEntry)

        }

        print("Array now has \(contentArray.count)")
        callback(contentArray)

    }) {(error) in print(error.localizedDescription)}
}
```

2nd, run this func in viewDidLoad(), and use call back to use the array entries with a for loop:

```
    getList { (data:[content]) in
        print("this is data from call back" )
        print(data)


        for contentEntry in data {
            print(contentEntry.ID)


                                    imgURL = self.storageRef!.child(contentEntry.ID)

                                    imgURL.getData(maxSize: Int64(1 * 1024 * 2000), completion: { (imageData, error) in
                                        if let error = error {
                                            print(error)
                                            print("===This is image Download error on=== \n")
                                            print("\(contentEntry.ID)")
                                            return
                                        } else {
                                            print("===This is image Download URL was used=== \n")
                                            print("\(contentEntry.ID)")
                                            print(imageData)
                                        }
                                    })
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Note, it is best to define a class for the data you want to store in the array in part one. It also makes calling back in part two much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is timing. You have asynchronous calls, the first one being to your FireBase DB. you start your for loop within the curly brackets of that, so there are no timing issues there, however, you then have an async call *within* the for loop. the for loop burns through before the async call gets started. You should use a for loop to create an array of URLs and then within your 2nd asynchronous call to `get data`, run a 2nd for loop using your array of URLs.